# java.lang.NullPointerException comes when running Master ireport when theres a sub report inside Master report

Tags: java, jasper-reports, subreport

My java code to run the report
[image]

DBConnector class

```
public class DBConnector {


private static final String url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/DB";
private static final String user = "postgres";
private static final String password = "123"; 

private Connection connection;
private static DBConnector dBConnector = null;

public DBConnector() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
    connection = null;

    Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
    connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);

    if (connection == null) {
        System.out.println("Failed to make connection!");
    }
}

private static DBConnector getDBConnector() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
    if (dBConnector == null) {
        dBConnector = new DBConnector();
    }
    return dBConnector;
}

public static Connection getConnectionToDB() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
    return getDBConnector().connection;
}
```

### Master report

parameters in Master report, this hotelid and custid are the parameters i want to sent to subreport
Both parameters are integers

[image]

parameter properties

[image]

subreport properties in Master report

[image]

2 properties defined

[image]

### Sub report

parameters in sub report

[image]

hotelid properties

[image]

Query in my subreport

select firstname,lastname 
from customers
where custid=$P{custid} and hotelid=$P{hotelid}

i get a NullPointerException when running the master report.
i can't find why its coming.
when i preview the report report is generating perfectly.
can some one please help me???

### Here's the error i get

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRPropertiesMap.readObject(JRPropertiesMap.java:185)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:974)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1846)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1753)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1329)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1945)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1869)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1753)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1329)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(ObjectInputStream.java:1667)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1323)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1945)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1869)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1753)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1329)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1945)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1869)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1753)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1329)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:351)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRLoader.loadObject(JRLoader.java:88)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRLoader.loadObjectFromLocation(JRLoader.java:257)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillSubreport.evaluateSubreport(JRFillSubreport.java:308)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillSubreport.evaluate(JRFillSubreport.java:257)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillElementContainer.evaluate(JRFillElementContainer.java:275)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillBand.evaluate(JRFillBand.java:426)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillBandNoOverflow(JRVerticalFiller.java:424)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillColumnHeader(JRVerticalFiller.java:467)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReportStart(JRVerticalFiller.java:251)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReport(JRVerticalFiller.java:113)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:891)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:795)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fillReport(JRFiller.java:63)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:402)
```

Comment: Please post your jrxml code for main report and sub report.

Comment: I mean jrxml file which create report.

Comment: `JRXmlLoader.load("./src/...")`
src? Really? "My java code to run the report".class don't know about directory "./src"